# Why has my executable size gone up from 780K to 1.1MB?

Tags: architecture, executable, filesize

I'm pretty sure I haven't changed the source or the makefile.  I'm using Linux on Fedora 19.  readelf is reporting it's now a UNIX - GNU, instead of a UNIX - System V, and byte 8 of the executable is 3 not 0.  Using nm on it I find many functions are changed and many added in.  But I didn't change anything in the source or makefile.  What's going on?  Why the filesize bloat?  And how dare it change something without my say-so?  Have I got a virus?

Extra Details

## g++ -v

Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=g++
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/libexec/gcc/i686-redhat-linux/4.8.1/lto-wrapper
Target: i686-redhat-linux
Configured with: ../configure --prefix=/usr --mandir=/usr/share/man --infodir=/usr/share/info --with-bugurl=http://bugzilla.redhat.com/bugzilla --enable-bootstrap --enable-shared --enable-threads=posix --enable-checking=release --with-system-zlib --enable-__cxa_atexit --disable-libunwind-exceptions --enable-gnu-unique-object --enable-linker-build-id --with-linker-hash-style=gnu --enable-languages=c,c++,objc,obj-c++,java,fortran,ada,go,lto --enable-plugin --enable-initfini-array --enable-java-awt=gtk --disable-dssi --with-java-home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.5.0-gcj-1.5.0.0/jre --enable-libgcj-multifile --enable-java-maintainer-mode --with-ecj-jar=/usr/share/java/eclipse-ecj.jar --disable-libjava-multilib --with-isl=/builddir/build/BUILD/gcc-4.8.1-20130603/obj-i686-redhat-linux/isl-install --with-cloog=/builddir/build/BUILD/gcc-4.8.1-20130603/obj-i686-redhat-linux/cloog-install --with-tune=generic --with-arch=i686 --build=i686-redhat-linux
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.8.1 20130603 (Red Hat 4.8.1-1) (GCC)

Comment: Hi Clive.. welcome to stack overflow. You might like to take the site tour (help->tour from the bar at the top of the page), which provides guidance about what sort of questions work well here and how to ask to get a good answer. I don't think you've provided enough details for anyone to even begin to guess what your problem is.

Answer (score 0):

I found it!  All on my own.  The linker was picking up the October 2007 versions of libc.a libm.a and libstdc++.a in the library directory I supplied (providing 780K executables).  After deleting those files it started picking up the March 2013 versions and so bloated the executable (1.1M).  I'll have to leave it bloated unfortunately because I don't want to have to find all the necessary header files (as of course the header files should match the libraries).  I don't blame the software writers for not putting one function per source/object file.  I blame the linker for still not dragging in function by function granularity and doing cyclic library search as standard.